# saxon 11, command line, parser config

Tags: saxon

Updating saxon he jar file to use 11.3

I had xerces in the classpath, then
-x:org.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader 
-y:org.xml.resolver.tools.ResolvingXMLReader 
-r:org.xml.resolver.CatalogResolver \

I'm guessing this is somewhat out of date?
https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!configuration/configuration-file

seems to leave xml parser config outside its scope?

Which jars and classes are current please?

Comment: Let's see what Michael says but I think with Saxon 11 integrating Norm's XmlResolver there is some default for e.g. catalog handling available, without needing to name specific resolvers. There is a `-catalog:files` command line option ("Here files is the catalog file to be searched, or a list of filenames separated by semicolons"). https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!sourcedocs

Answer (score 0):

While it's still possible in principle to use the Apache resolver (it implements standard EntityResolver and URIResolver interfaces, after all), the new XmlResolver from Norm Tovey-Walsh is integrated into Saxon 11 and I would advise using that instead. All you need to do is nominate a catalog file (using -catalog), and everything should swing into place.